# Integrating iAd and AdMob through Mobclix on iPhone

Tags: iphone, admob, iad, mobclix

I am a bit confused about what to do.
I have installed Moblicx SDK 4.4.4.
I read here (http://blog.mobclix.com/2010/07/13/mobclix-ios-sdk-4-1-now-available/) that nothing special is necessary to implement iAd and AdMob, just enable iAds and add the framework (I did that) and add the AdMob SDK to my projet (also did that). And make all the calls to Mobclix functions. I did all that too.
But it is confusing since in my dashboard when I enabled those networks it said "You are responsible for implementing the logic in your application to handle the requests from this network".
So now.. my question is.. is it enough just to do this, so the Mobclix will handle everything else?

```
-(BOOL)adView:(MobclixAdView*)adView shouldHandleSuballocationRequest:(MCAdsSuballocationType)suballocationType
{
if (suballocationType == kMCAdsSuballocationAdMob) return YES;
if (suballocationType == kMCAdsSuballocationIAd) return YES;

return NO;
}
```

When I run my app I see the test add, but how do I know the iAds and AdMob are setup correctly?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Hey, same here for me. I'd like to know how to do this properly as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the answers are actually in the Documentation folder when you downloaded Mobclix SDK. I just copied the actual SDK folder and did not really see other folder in the ZIP file. Anyway, after reading the documentation, what you did is right. But you are missing one more delegate, and that is to handle admob ads publisher id.

```
-(NSString *)adView:(MobclixAdView *)adView publisherKeyForSuballocationRequest:(MCAdsSuballocationType)suballocationType {

    return @"You Admob ID Here";
}
```

Also to answer about why you are just getting test ads - have you properly set the Test Ads settings in mobclix dashboard to off for the ad size that you are using? Check the settings properly. Also, for testing admob, you can just put allocation for admob to 100%. I just did this and admob is showing fine in my app through mobclix. Hope that helps.